# How to map through all children with Ant Design Tree Node

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tree, antd

I have a an array which looks similar to this:

```
const hierarchy = [
  {
    hierarchyId: 1,
    hierarchyName: 'John'
    children: [
      {
        hierarchyId: 2,
        hierarchyName: 'Mary',
        children: []
      },
      {
        hierarchyId: 3,
        hierarchyName: 'Jane',
        children: [
          {
            hierarchyId: 4,
            hierarchyName: 'Joan',
            children: []
          },
          {
            hierarchyId: 5,
            hierarchyName: 'Jim',
            children: [
              {
                hierarchyId: 6,
                hierarchyName: 'Mike',
                children: []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And I want to represent this on an Ant Design Tree. But I want to be able to add buttons and possibly another column to a TreeNode in the Tree.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Tree } from 'antd'
const { TreeNode } = Tree

const TreeComponent = ({ hierarchy }) => {
  return (
    <Tree>
      {hierarchy.map(res => {
        return (
          <TreeNode
            key={res.hierarchyId}
            title={(
              <div>
                <span>{res.hierarchyName}</span>
                <span>Another Column</span>
                <button>Click here</button>
              </div>
          )}>
            {res.children.map(r => {
              <TreeNode
                key={res.hierarchyId}
                title={(
                <div>
                  <span>{res.hierarchyName}</span>
                  <span>Another Column</span>
                  <button>Click here</button>
               </div>
              )} />
            })}
          </TreeNode>
        )
      }}
    </Tree>
  )
}

export default TreeComponent
```

Now obviously the above would only show 2 levels deep in the tree, I'm wondering if there were say 10 levels (or any amount really) how I would dynamically display each level in the tree without knowing how deep it goes and still be able to add a button and another column to the TreeNode?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using this simple solution:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Tree } from 'antd'
const { TreeNode } = Tree

const TreeComponent = ({ hierarchy }) => {
  const renderTreeNodes = data =>
    data.map(item => {
      if (item.children) {
        return (
          <TreeNode title={item.title} key={item.key} dataRef={item}>
            {renderTreeNodes(item.children)}
          </TreeNode>
        )
      }
      return <TreeNode key={item.key} {...item} />
    })

  return (
    <Tree>
      {renderTreeNodes(hierarchy)}
    </Tree>
  )
}

export default TreeComponent
```

Which I found here: [Ant design Tree defaultExpandAll doesnt work with button click for react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59891806/ant-design-tree-defaultexpandall-doesnt-work-with-button-click-for-react)